# ValueError: Could not unserialize key data

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a key in a `json` file and I am trying to feed this file into Google Playstore's authorization protocol. Shown below is what I have tried:

```
    #authorization key

        config = {
            "type": "abc",
            "project_id": "abc",
            "private_key_id": "123",
            "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----[REDACTED]\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
            "client_email": "abc@service-account.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
            "client_id": "345",
            "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
            "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/cert",
            "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/reporting%service-account.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
        }

    #Put auth key  into json file
    dbutils.fs.put("Temp/123.json",json.dumps(config))

    #Feed authorization key into Google Cloud Storage (GCS) account.
    path='Temp/123.json'
    storage_client = google.cloud.storage.Client.from_service_account_json(path)
```

But the following error is being thrown:

> ValueError: Could not unserialize key data. 
>       info, require=['client_email', 'token_uri'])

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure config dict was written to 'Temp/123.json'. Check it on disk and verify it was written as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error seems to be that the private key has a wrong format.

Try using another key; you can create it in the Console, going to "IAM & admin" -> "Service accounts" -> [account], and there editing the account and clicking on the "CREATE KEY" button.

Also, it seems you are using an [old version](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/commit/1341bb71ee21f1bc48b5ad7e5a3db0f378206200#diff-29b17fd6522fb7c1388d06f421d77734) of the `cryptography` package.

Comment: @Tina could you accept this answer if it solved your issue? Thanks!